# How to detetc hardware acceleration in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, windows-10, h.264, hardware-acceleration

I am writing c++ program to screen record by ffmpeg 4.3! I need to detect hardware acceleration support such as **h264_qsv** or **h264_nvenc** without running ffmpeg.exe!

I explored ffmpeg.exe source code and found no results! some solutions are deprecated or dose not work on 4.3!
As instance,

```
avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("h264_qsv")
```

returns **null** even it is exist and works properly!